# Why does my Import in React change my layout without me implementing the imported component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Issue: The import statement on line 1 from App.js imports a component called Box. However, without me implementing the  component in App.js, the Box still appears on my screen.

**App.js**

```js
import Box from './Box';
import React from 'react'

function App() {
  return (
      <div>
      </div>
    )
  }

export default App;
```

**Box.js**

```js
import React from 'react'

function Box() {
    return (<div style={{height:'30px', width:'30px', backgroundColor:'black'}}></div>)

}

export default Box;
```

The output:
[image]

Comment: You check if `box.css` has css definitions that applies to `div`

Comment: @ryeballar box.css is actually an empty file

Comment: try to check your index.js

Comment: @edhi.uchiha i checked too

Comment: try to return some other tag other than <div> from App (ex string) to debug. Try clearing the cache.